# rdlc report how to collapse a table rather than just hide?

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

I have rdlc report in which i am showing or hiding a rectangle(in which it consists of consists of no.of tables and text boxes etc.). If the rectangle is hide, then also it is taking certain amount of space which is allocated to that so in my report extra blank page is coming after exporting to Word.
  I have tried with Row Visibility property to the table inside rectangle but it is also not working.
 Could you please help on this.
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one "Detail Section" and put rectangle inside that "Detail Section" after that you can hide/show that section rather than rectangle.

Comment: Hi koras, thanks for reply..could u pls tell how to add "detail section"? is it for whole report or something else?

Comment: Do following steps Right Click on Detail Section > Section Export > Select Details > Insert

Comment: Hi koras, i dont know what is detail section? could you pls tell what is that and how to add detail section in my report? thanks in advance.